# No Gmail unread count in Mail.app - why?

Tags: macos, email, gmail

I have no Gmail unread count (circled mail count) in Mail.app on the Macbook pro (10.10.3). I mean not the dock icon but the in the app itself (a circled number to the right of the Gmail inbox). Why so?
Other mails accounts (from other sources) work perfect.

This is really annoying.
Has anyone else seen this behaviour, and can anything be done about it?

Comment: solution: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH11704?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US